# Custom Filter on values in a dataframe column (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column which has values of 6 charaters, followed by "-", followed by a number. I want to replace the original value with the number only.

For example - If the column has a value of ABCXYZ-123. I need to replace it with 123. Need it for all the rows of that column.

I was also able to right an Excel formula for the same - ***=NUMBERVALUE(MID(B2,(FIND("-",B2)+1),LEN(B2)))***

How to do the same in Python?

Comment: are you using any library to read excel in python?

Comment: Yes. I am using Pandas

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(lambda x: x.split("-")[-1])
```

Replace `col1` with your column name

Comment: why not used `str` pandas functions?

Comment: @jezrael coz I couldn't come up with `.str.str` part

Answer (score 1):

I prefer here [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `str[-1]`:

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].str.str.split("-").str[-1]
```

Comment: should be faster then apply